# Is checking the type of a variable antithetical to OOP?

Tags: object-oriented, language-features

As an example, in `PHP` you can run

```
gettype($myVariable);
```

to obtain the type of a variable `$myVariable`.

Is such functionality antithetical to OOP principles?

Comment: yes but there is also the expression problem https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-expression-problem-and-its-solutions

Comment: Note that making your programs completely pure OOP may be not ideal itself. Often a mixture of paradigms is better, as some problems are easier solved with other approaches. So even if type testing is bad OOP, it could be good in a particular place.

Answer (score 5):

It depends, but often it is, especially when the type is then used in a type comparison using a chain of if-statements or a switch or select. It means that we're not using polymorphism and we're probably violating the Open-Closed Principle (OCP) and the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP).

The effect of this is that when you add a new type next to the existing type, you also have to go to all places in the code where the type check occurs and change those as well. It violates the SRP because you are changing more than one place in the code. And it violates the OCP because you have to change existing code for adding a new feature rather than simply adding new code.

That said, there are situations where using this can make sense, for example, when you have naturally parallel type hierarchies for design patterns like strategy. But in that case, it's better to still avoid a direct type check and instead use the type as a key to a map, where the behavior that differs between types is the value, and a mechanism that populates the map automatically so that you still get the maintainability benefits from the OCP and the SRP. In Java, such a mechanism is provided by `java.util.ServiceLoader`. I'm sure that a similar mechanism exists in PHP as well.

Last but not least, switching the paradigm away from OOP to some other paradigm will not invalidate the SRP and OCP, and will not remove the maintainability question at hand.

Comment: I'm not really clear how a map using the type as keys is different from a switch or chain of ifs, and when it would be necessary to use instead of polymorphism. The "mechanism to populate the map automatically" seems to be the important part, but you don't really explain how that would work - are you talking about some kind of registry that types can be added to?

Comment: A map with keys is different from a switch or chain of ifs because it is more maintainable and less redundant. The switch or chain of ifs may be required in more than one place of the code. The map would simply be used, the initialization of the map would be in a central place.

A possible mechanism to populate the map is described in my answer, it is `java.util.ServiceLoader`.

Comment: OK, so you've edited in a class name, but that means very little to anyone who's never used Java, and it still feels like the emphasis of the answer is on the wrong part.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes...

I firmly stand on the side of disliking upcasting (i.e. from a base type to a derived type) as it is predominantly a code smell and sign of polymorphism abuse.

The most commonly used example of a LSP violation shows you exactly why relying on upcasting upcasting is a bad idea.

```
void MakeDuckSwim(IDuck duck)
{
    if (duck is ElectricDuck)
        ((ElectricDuck)duck).TurnOn();
    duck.Swim();
}
```

[Others have explained the issue better than I could](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/202896/liskovs-substitution-principle), so I won't delve into it here.

This is also why I'm not a big fan of e.g. [the new C#9 `switch` examples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/) that in their announcement examples explicitly show code that figures out which derived type a variable of a base type can be converted to<sup>1</sup>.

```
public static decimal CalculateToll(object vehicle) =>
    vehicle switch
    {
        DeliveryTruck t when t.GrossWeightClass > 5000 => 10.00m + 5.00m,
        DeliveryTruck t when t.GrossWeightClass < 3000 => 10.00m - 2.00m,
        DeliveryTruck _ => 10.00m,

        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Not a known vehicle type", nameof(vehicle))
    };
```

Not that there aren't possible fringe cases where this could be useful, but using it as the *guiding* example on how to use a language feature is going to telegraph to developers that this sort of logic is the norm, which it **really** shouldn't be.

As a code reviewer, I will always flag upcasting logic as an issue unless there is a clear reason why upcasting is warranted (or the lesser of the evils).

---

### **But ...**

There are fringe cases where this is valid. I can think of three main examples, which I'll list. Other cases may exist but they don't come to mind right now.

**1**

Exceptions are, funnily enough, an exception to my dismissal of upcasting logic. `try catch` logic specifically exists to figure out the type of an exception to then handle that exception appropriately according to its type.
But this is a matter of logical consequence. You could avoid needing to upcast exceptions, but then you'd be forced to define different ways for different exception types to bubble up, which mostly defeats the purpose of having a streamlined throwing and catching process that ensure the thrower doesn't need to worry about the catcher.

**2**

A second exception here are cases where the derived type is only going to be used as e.g. a string value (for its name). Here, the subtype isn't really used in a "typed" sense, it's a simple scalar value and it doesn't affect the logic of the application. For example:

```
public interface INamedObject { string Name { get; set; } }

public void HandleNamedObject(INamedObject o)
{
    string typeName = o.GetType().Name;
    _log.Debug($"Handling named object of type {typename} with name {o.Name}");

    // business logic
}
```

That's completely harmless and the application's logic doesn't rely on this derived type in any way.

**3**

When serializing an object that you intend to deserialize in the future, you're going to have to keep track of the exact type of an object so that you can deserialize it back to that type. If your serialization logic is written to handle a base type, you're going to have to figure out the derived type to ensure you can deserialize the object in the future.

```
public IFoo Example(IFoo myFoo)
{
    Type exactType = myFoo.GetType();

    string serialized = Serialize(myFoo);

    IFoo deserialized = Deserialize(serialized, exactType);
}
```

This is a bit of an oversimplification, but this is how serialized data stores usually work when a particular store isn't inherently bound to a concrete type (with no further subtypes).

As a real world example, we store events in a single table, but since each event is a type of its own, we store the event using two columns: the type (name string) and the event data (json string). This allows us to cast these events back to their specific type when we retrieve the data.

***Note**: Some serialization libraries can be configured to automatically serialize the object's type so that you don't need to manually track the type. Newtonsoft is one such library.*

---

<sup>1</sup> As @IMSoP points out in the comments, the C# 9 `switch` example may have been a feature developed for FP rather than OOP, which would nullify my objections to the feature itself.

Comment: Regarding pattern-matching switch, I believe it has come from an FP, rather than OOP, background, which explains why it feels contrary to polymorphism. It makes particular sense when the set of types is a closed list (e.g. algebraic data types, sealed classes) since then you can prove the switch is exhaustive without adding a default branch.

Comment: @IMSoP: Fair enough. I'm not FP-experienced enough to make that judgment, I'll amend my answer with your comment.

Comment: @Flater moment^^, i think you mix here two things into one pot, that not belongs together. Yeah the example with the duck is a classical break with the idea from baraara liskov. the invariants are changed from the subclass. And thats the violation. To make these invariants right again by caling the right methods in the subclass and before by checking the type if it is the subclass give us the right result, but with a much bad design^^. So what i want to say: To fix something (the really bad designed subclass) with casting is bad, but is that tool at all bad?

Comment: lets say i have scredriver and now i want to use the scredriver to cook my launch. I think in that context it is bad, because the screedriver is missused in that CONTEXT. But is the screedriver in all cases bad? No the CONTEXT (the bad subclass) is bad, not tool (screedriver). So you cant argue that the tool is bad, because the context is bad

Comment: But yes the other points with polymorphism are correct, and dependency inversion and so on.... But sometimes its easier not using a visitor and to write really down fast a few switch-caseses^^

Comment: @RobinKreuzer: _"To fix something (the really bad designed subclass) with casting is bad, but is that tool at all bad?"_ Your argument relies on your screwdriver being able to be used for a good reason in other scenarios. My point is that there is hardly any good reason to ever cast to your derived type. By and large, this is something that is better avoided. Barring the exceptions I listed in this answer, there is IMHO no good reason to ever do so, as it will generally be a patch on a bad design; where the solution is to fix the bad design rather than patch it. [..]

Comment: @RobinKreuzer [..] Note that I am open to extending that list of exceptions if anyone can argue another valid use case. _"So you cant argue that the tool is bad, because the context is bad"_ What you're saying is correct but you've misunderstood what I'm saying. I'm arguing that there's hardly any good context in which to cast from a base type to a derived type, as this almost invariably ends up being used as a way to circumvent (the intention of) polymorphism in OOP. If there is virtually no good context in which to use a tool, then the tool can reasonably be labeled as bad in most cases.

Comment: @Flater Would checking types for the purpose of comparing two objects (as used with `getClass()` in Java for overriding the `equals()` method) also fall under the fringe cases?

Comment: @MehdiCharife: It hinges on your definition of equality, and the point of making that method overridable is specifically to allow you to redefine it - I can't answer this definitively. What I would say is this: is you consider `myBaseObject1` and `myBaseObject2` (different instances of the same class) to be equal because all of their property values match, i.e. you are defining equality to look at values, not instances; then in my opinion `myBaseObject1` and `myDerivedObject1` should **also be equal** (assuming that all of their `MyBase` properties contain the same values as each other).

Comment: @MehdiCharife: ... The reason I say this because I think that _not_ doing the latter would then be a violation of LSP. _However_, equality is an interesting case in point because it's so difficult to establish precisely how and why you are defining your equality type a certain way, so there is leeway in this answer. I'd urge you to consider LSP but I'm open to justifiable reasoning in either direction.

Comment: @Flater While the `equals()` method is certainly overridable, its signature enforces that your overriding method accepts an argument of type `Object`. Since the user of `equals()` can technically pass any `Object` to it, it seems unsafe to downcast the argument and compare the fields before checking that the provided argument falls under the same class. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

Sometimes you're stuck between a rock and a hard place, though: if the objects that your code needs to deal with have differences in behavior which would break your code if you don't handle them specially. For example, if a library that you're using has a known bug that won't be fixed, and it causes your program to crash when you send `bar` to an object of type `Foo`, you might be forced to check the type even though that's unclean.

Of course, your own code should never force its users to perform such workarounds.

Answer (score -2):

Not *really*. For example, Objective-C and Swift let you put *anything* into an array: var a = [Any]; a.add(1); a.add(“hello”); a.add(someObject())

In Swift you don’t check for the type of an item, but do an optional cast:

```
If let i = a[0] as? Int {
} else if let s = a[0] as? String {
} else if let o = a[0] as? SomeClass {
}
```

It’s not object oriented but then not everything has to be object oriented. Importantly, everything *is* typechecked. i is 100% an Int, s is 100% a String, o is 100% SomeClass. You use whatever is best.

Comment: Polymorphism is a staple of OO, which means that your example inherently applies to every OO language (i.e. you can have a collection with base-typed elements even if the elements themselves are of a derived type). But, as [as Ian Malcolm said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY-pUxKQMUE)... Your answer is showing that it _can_ be done (which OP's question also shows), it doesn't explain why it should(n't) be done, which is the core question here.